# WCF Service caching data?

Tags: .net, winforms, wcf, entity-framework-4

I have a WCF service that takes in and Id and generates some records. The service uses Entity Framework for data access.

There is only one method in the service and it returns void. The method is called from a 1.1 .net winforms app.
This is the code I am using to call the service:

```
ChangeRoutingService.ChangeRouting changeRoutingService = new ChangeRoutingService.ChangeRouting();
changeRoutingService.RouteCorrespondence(Id, true);
```

The winforms app updates a record before calling the service. The service then tries to find the record that has been updated but when I step through the code running the service locally, in EF the record has been updated but when I try this on our live deployed service the record has not been updated! The winforms app access the DB directly while EF in the service hits a DB which uses a linked server.

Is EF\WCF caching data? Is the winforms app reusing the connection to the server?

No sure what's going on here, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

Entity framework was caching data so I ran Refresh to update the data.